# Multi-file template can can not used in WebAPI projects but in classlib C# VisualStudio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, templates, visual-studio-2017

For some reasons I can not see my exported template on any WebAPI project (created using dotnet new webapi) but I can see the template in classlib projects,

my template is stored, in a zipped file in

`C:\Users\rakia\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Templates\ItemTemplates`

and look like this:

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="Item">
  <TemplateData>
  <DefaultName>Constellation Model.cs</DefaultName>
  <Name>Constellation Model</Name>
  <Description>&lt;Aucune description disponible&gt;</Description>
  <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
  <SortOrder>10</SortOrder>
  <Icon>__TemplateIcon.ico</Icon>
</TemplateData>
<TemplateContent>
  <References />
  <ProjectItem SubType="" TargetFileName="Handlers/$fileinputname$CommandsHandler.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">Handlers/ModelCommandsHandler.cs</ProjectItem>
  <ProjectItem SubType="" TargetFileName="Handlers/$fileinputname$EventsHandler.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">Handlers/ModelEventsHandler.cs</ProjectItem>

  <ProjectItem SubType="" TargetFileName="Domain/Models/$fileinputname$.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">Domain/Models/Model.cs</ProjectItem>

  <ProjectItem SubType="" TargetFileName="Domain/Repositories/$fileinputname$Repository.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">Domain/Repositories/ModelRepository.cs</ProjectItem>
  <ProjectItem SubType="" TargetFileName="Domain/Repositories/I$fileinputname$Repository.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">Domain/Repositories/IModelRepository.cs</ProjectItem>

  <ProjectItem SubType="" TargetFileName="Controllers/$fileinputname$Controller.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">Controllers/ModelController.cs</ProjectItem>

  <ProjectItem SubType="" TargetFileName="Bus/$fileinputname$/$fileinputname$Commands.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">Bus/Model/ModelCommands.cs</ProjectItem>
  <ProjectItem SubType="" TargetFileName="Bus/$fileinputname$/$fileinputname$Events.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">Bus/Model/ModelEvents.cs</ProjectItem>

</TemplateContent>
```

here what I see when trying to create my exported template in WebAPI
[image]

and here what i see when trying to create my exported template in classlib
[image]

My first guess would be that the ProjectType in the vstemplate file is wrong because VisualStudio doesnt consider WebAPI projects to be CSharp project ? but then i wouldn't know what to put inside project type, i tried leaving it empty and nothing worked out

Answer (score 0):

Got it fixed by finding the class template for ASP Core project and found this:

```
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <TemplateGroupID>AspNetCore</TemplateGroupID>
    <TemplateID>AspNetCore.Class</TemplateID>
```

you still need ProjectType as CSharp but have to add a template group id of AspNetCore
However i now experience problem because there is too much files in my template and it doesnt work with aspcore...
I guess that's another whole problem and won't continue here